# Java method call format

Tags: java, android

I'm just learning java, I found calling methods two ways the both work, but I'm not sure if there is a preferred way.

```
 /**
 * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
 */
public void submitOrder(View view) {
    int price = calculatePrice();
    String orderSummary = createOrderSummary(price);
    displayMessage(orderSummary);

}
```

vs

```
public void submitOrder(View view) {
    displayMessage(createOrderSummary(calculatePrice()));
}
```

would this be considered poor code? or wrong in anyway?

Comment: Purely a style thing, depends on the case. The first one will also be easier to debug (you can set breakpoints on each line, exception stack trace line numbers are easier to read).

Comment: Not wrong. But the upper is slightly more debuggable because you can set breakpoints to each step and will find distinct line numbers in Exceptions Stacktrace. And: If you are paid by LOC, ... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standardized approach of invoking methods in a certain fashion.

It all depends on the developer writing the code or the team in your work place in general.

One of the most important factors to consider would be how readable your code is. If one approach is more readable than the other, then you could go with that.

Remember that when you develop code, especially at work, there would be several other developers who would maintain code in the future. So, readability and clarity and maintainability of code becomes important.

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's not wrong, but the second way is definitely harder to read and understand.
The first method is preferable as it will make your code much easier to understand and debug by you and others